# Connection closed when calling fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Tags: java, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am sending notification pushes to browsers from my Java backend server and recently I've been getting a lot of Connections Closed exceptions.  I use [Java Web Push library](https://github.com/web-push-libs/webpush-java).

This issue started around December 23, 2020 (not a significant date from my perspective, but perhaps there was some update that I'm not aware of...)

Here is a sample stacktrace, I'm hoping that I can get some ideas of how to tackle this issue. As far as I understand, if the registration is invalid or expired, I would still receive an HTTP status code that I can react to. A connection closed is unexpected and I do not know whether the records I have is valid or not.

I think it is unlikely that the error has to do with the Web Push library. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
     at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.getResult(BasicFuture.java:71)
     at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.get(BasicFuture.java:84)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:70)
     at nl.martijndwars.webpush.PushService.send(PushService.java:118)
     at my.package.MyClass.sendNotification(MyClass.java:xx)
     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
     at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.endOfInput(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:347)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:261)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:121)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
     ... 1 more
Caused by:
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed
     at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.endOfInput(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:347)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:261)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:121)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
     at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```